# dynamic control RegisterRequiresControlState

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

i use my web.config file to define a menu it work fine. But to improve system i want to store my created menu control in an object menu_ to reuse it on next call.

if i add menu_ control to my master page (like i did with generated version) i have a RegisterRequiresControlState error :

RegisterRequiresControlState could not be call before or after prerender.

```
    public class tabloidMenu : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    private Menu menu_;

    static public explicit operator Menu(tabloidMenu configMenu)
    {
        if (configMenu.menu_ != null) return configMenu.menu_;

        Menu menu = new Menu();

        menu.CssClass = "menu";
        menu.EnableViewState = false;
        menu.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Disabled;
        menu.IncludeStyleBlock = false;
        menu.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;


        if (tabloidConfigMenu.configMenu != null)
        {
            foreach (tabloidConfigMenuItem item in configMenu)
            {
                menu.Items.Add((MenuItem)item);
            }
        }

        configMenu.menu_=menu;

        return menu;
    }
```

in my master page i use

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool popupMode = Page.Request["mode"] == "popup";

            if (!popupMode)
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink cssLink = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink();
                cssLink.Href = "~/Styles/Site.css";
                cssLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
                cssLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
                Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssLink);

                //add menu

                if (Tabloid.tabloidConfigMenu.configMenu != null)
                {
                    Menu mn = (Menu)Tabloid.tabloidConfigMenu.configMenu.TopMenu;
                    mn.EnableViewState = false;
                    mn.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Disabled;
                    Page.Master.FindControl("MenuHolder").Controls.Add(mn);
                }
                else
                {
                    Label l = new Label();
                    l.Text = Tabloid.tabloidConfigMenu.lastError;
                    Page.Master.FindControl("MenuHolder").Controls.Add(l);
                }
            }
```

do you have an idea.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think you answered your own question, the error tells you to load the control in prerender event handler. BTW if you are working on asp.net please tag it.

Comment: i try it but i have same response. I choose to use page_init but always same error? I don't understand why behaviour is different when i use menu_

Comment: can you post the code that loads the control after you do
        **configMenu.menu_=menu;**